# If $\tan x + \cot x$ is a positive integer, will $\tan^2 x+ \cot ^2 x -1$ also be a positive integer?

Tags: trigonometry

> If $\tan x + \cot x$ is a positive integer, will $\tan^2 x+ \cot ^2 x -1$ also be a positive integer?

It's needed for another example, and I'm stuck here. Could you please help me? I have no idea what to do. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Consider $(\tan x + \cot x)^2$.

Comment: I even used it a few lines below this, I don't know how I missed that!  Thank You very much :)

Answer (score 2):

doesn't matter where it starts, you have a real number $r = \tan x.$ Your integer is
$$ n = r + \frac{1}{r} $$
$$ n^2 = r^2 + 2 + \frac{1}{r^2} $$
$$ n^2 -3 = r^2 +  \frac{1}{r^2} - 1 $$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint 1:**
$$
\left(t+\frac1t\right)^2-3=t^2+\frac1{t^2}-1
$$
**Hint 2:** the minimum of $t+\frac1t$ for $t\gt0$ is $2$.